# Android detect general keyboard events made by other apps?

Tags: android, keyboard, detection, broadcast

Is there a way to detect some general keyboard events made by other apps? I understand that the specific keyboard events(e.g. key "b" pressed) should not be exposed due to security reason. But are general events like keyboard show/hide broadcast in any way? I did some search but did not find it available.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard show/hide is not an event you can listen for, not even in your own app (there are some hacky workarounds within your app, but it seems like you want to do this externally). I don't believe keyboard events are broadcast in any way. They may be delivered to the current Activity window in focus (and to its Views), but I have seen nothing to suggest that they are broadcast across the system.